# >= Operand cannot be applied to types Bool and Float

Tags: c#, boolean, operand

I have this long if statement. Its giving me the error

`>= Operand cannot be applied to types Bool and Float`

```
if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed && 
    (tl.Position.X >= harePlayer.Position.X >= tl.Position.X && 
     tl.Position.Y >= harePlayer.Position.Y &&
     harePlayer.Position.X <= (harePlayer.Position.X + 52) &&
     tl.Position.Y <= (harePlayer.Position.Y + 50)))
```

Could anyone tell me what the fix is? Thank you. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but `harePlayer.Position.X <= (harePlayer.Position.X + 52)` is always true unless harePlayer.Position.X is NaN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tl.Position.X >= harePlayer.Position.X >= tl.Position.X` is not correct c# condition. You have to write two separate conditions and merge them using `&&`:

```
tl.Position.X >= harePlayer.Position.X && harePlayer.Position.X >= tl.Position.X
```

Comment: and please refactor that to `tl.Position.X == harePlayer.Position.X` (or have I finally lost it?)

Comment: Regardless, it worked and you fixed it! Thanks a lot buddy. :)